# prove that $\int_X f=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(\{x|f(x)>t\})dm(t)$

Tags: measure-theory

I've encountered two similar statements that I don't know how to prove.

$1.$ let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. let $f:X\to [0,\infty)$ be measurable. Show that:

$\int_X fd\mu =\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(\{x|f(x)>t\})dm(t)$

$2.$ let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a complete measure space. let $f\in L^1(\mu)$ be non-negative. Show that:

$\int_X f d\mu=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(\{x|f(x)\ge t\})dm(t)$

I've tried to solve it but i'm not even sure what is $m(t)$ and how do I integrate over

$\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(\{x|\chi_A>t\})dm(t)$,  for $f=\chi_A$

how do I continue?

Comment: $mR$ is Lebesgue measure and the result is an easy consequence of Fubini's Theorem  . Almost any book on Probability Theory has  a proof.

Comment: I believe this is true for the second statement, yet the first one is introduced before discussing Fubini's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $m$ is Lebesgue measure, we indeed get
$$
\int_{(0, \infty)} \mu(\chi_A > t) dm(t) = \int_{(0, \infty)} \mu(A) \mathbf{1}_{t \in [0, 1)} dm(t) = \mu(A) = \int_X \chi_A d\mu.
$$
By linearity and measure additivity, this result is valid for positive linear *disjoint* combinations of indicator functions, and we note that by pruning negative terms, the Lebesgue integral is approximated by these arbitrarily well, so that using monotonicity, we already obtain
$$
\int_{(0, \infty)} \mu(f > t) dm(t) \ge \int_X f d\mu,
$$
(similarly for the same formula with $\ge$ sign) with the reverse inequality following if we can prove that
$$
\int_{(0, \infty)} \mu(f_n > t) dm(t) \to \int_{(0, \infty)} \mu(f > t) dm(t),
$$
where $f_n \uparrow f$ is a sequence of simple functions (resp. a similar claim for the $\ge$ sign). In order to do that, we use eg. majorised convergence for 2; for 1., one would have to concoct a direct proof using a finite countable cover.

Of course, Mr. Murti's suggestion of using Fubini's theorem also leads to a proof.